# How to create and run .asp extension file in visual web developer 2008

Tags: visual-studio, asp-classic

I want to know if it is possible to create and run .asp file in Microsoft visual web developer 2008?

The problem is that there is no inbuilt .asp extension file given in visual web 
developer 2008.

If anyone knows how to create and run this, please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create them - they're just text files - but whether or not Intelisense will work or not I don't know.  I don't think the built-in development server will handle Classic ASP - you will need to run the pages under IIS instead.

Comment: The intellisense works with SP1 in both VS2008 and the Express version

Answer (score 1):

You have to use IIS and depending on the version of IIS you are using, you need to create the new web application in IIS, and specify a separate application pool for it to run in as .net or Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

.asp is the Classic ASP file extension.  ASP.NET uses .aspx as the file extension for web pages.

It has some others as well, such as .asmx for web services.